# Why does an improper rotation axis preclude chirality?

Tags: chirality, symmetry

Can anybody prove that any molecule with an axis of improper rotation is nonchiral? I still do not understand why this is so, any proper mathematical proof or visualisation of a generalised molecule would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you understand why _mirror_ symmetry means no chirality, to begin with?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/142244/example-of-an-achiral-molecule-without-a-plane-of-symmetry-or-inversion-center https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/51854/does-an-axis-of-symmetry-determine-chiralty

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/145084/what-are-the-criteria-for-a-molecule-to-be-chiral

Comment: Still none of them have a proper proof why an axis of improper rotation means no chirality, the most these answers have is examples